# Storing dicts/namedtuple from DB-query in session-object in Flask throws "TypeError: can't pickle sqlite3.Row objects"

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary, session, flask

Working on my 1st baby project with Flask. It's a game and my goal is to store the user's current "live game" and "team"(group) in the session-dict, so I don't have to run the DB-query every time a route gets called (I can't think of any other way to 'centrally' store & pass around this data elegantly).

So I am doing that in my code "new_game" (attached) in lines 13 & 14. The get_db() function (found here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/sqlite3/) returns a namedtuple - also attached my implementation of it.

These lines have led to my debugger dumping "TypeError: can't pickle sqlite3.Row objects". Now, I suspected that maybe namedtuple as a type is the problem and encapsulated the get_db() with dict(), but that didn't change anything. 
Looks to me like a common thing with a very obvious solution for experienced folks... so any help/hints/background on this would be highly appreciated! ☺️

```
@app.route("/new_game", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def new_game():
  # get group_name from form & initiating user's turn
  if request.method == "POST":
    group_name = request.form.get("group")
    row = query_db("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_name=? AND user_id=?",[group_name, session["user_id"]], one=True)

    # new DB entry for new game
    get_db().execute("INSERT INTO games (active, turn, group_name) VALUES (:active, :turn, :group_name)", {"active":1, "turn":row["turn"], "group_name":row["group_name"]})
    get_db().commit()
    #store user's live game and group in session
    session["game"] = query_db("SELECT * FROM games INNER JOIN groups ON groups.group_name=games.group_name INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id=groups.user_id WHERE users.user_id=? AND games.active=?", [session["user_id"], 1], one=True)
    session["gamegroup"] = query_db("SELECT * FROM groups INNER JOIN games ON games.group_name=groups.group_name INNER JOIN users ON groups.user_id=users.user_id WHERE groups.user_id=? AND games.active=?", [session["user_id"], 1], one=True)
    return render_template("live_game.html", turn=row["turn"], round=1, isturn=True, group_name=group_name)
  else:
    return redirect("/new_game")
###########################################

def get_db():
  db=getattr(g, '_database', None)
  if db is None:
    db = g._database = sqlite3.connect("ce.db")
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
  return db

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but storing the namedtuple instead of each values in their own cell is a bad idea. First you need to call the db anyway, retrive a row or one cell will change nothing in term of performance. Second point, you will avoid headaches and bad implementation by putting only proper values type instead of a python type.

Comment: Thank you - not related but still helpful. Turns out that if I (sort of) follow your advice and store my retrieved row/cell in as an actual dict-variable (instead of the variable returned by the row_factory which kind of just mimics a tuple, but isn't one), it worked! But are you suggesting rather storing each value in a dedicated cell in a local variable? That seems a bit onerous and verbose given I have quite a few routes and my code just gets lengthy if I don't access  the data via the session-dict... thanks again!